# scrollview with storyboard ios

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am trying to do a ScrollView from a storyboard in xcode4, but nothing works. I can do a scrollview with nibs in xcode4, but not storyboards. Anyone know how to do this?

Help me and you save a kitten!

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works" ?? Does your project compile? Display anything onscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind, the scrollview in the storyboard was sized bigger than i defined it in the .m file, so while it compiled, it didn't scroll. size the scrollview in the storyboard to the size of the screen or smaller and it will scroll.